# Initialisation, failed to determine IP address

Tags: nitro

Thought I'd give Nitro a whirl but can't get past initialisation.

```
Initialize the primary machine now? [yes] 
How many CPU cores? [2]
How much memory? [4G]
How much disk space? [40G]
Which version of PHP? [7.4]
Which database engine? [mysql] 
Which version of mysql? [5.7] 
Applying the changes now...
launch failed: The following errors occurred:
failed to determine IP address
Error: exit status 2
ianebden@Ians-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Anyone else encountered this? Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug... I'd recommend filing an issue here for it: https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues

Comment: Done. https://github.com/craftcms/nitro/issues/224